# Selenium Webdriver is sending Keys, but no text is displaying in the fields

Tags: text, selenium, webdriver, field, sendkeys

I'm using selenium webdriver Chrome. I'm seeing something so odd. I'm testing a sign up account. Webdriver is going to each field and it looks like it is input-ing text, but nothing is being displayed. There are no text results being displayed in the fields. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Test
public void testAlreadyUsedEmailSignUp() throws InterruptedException {
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body.oneColFixCtrHdr div.container div#header div#innerHeader div#menu ul div.btn-gr")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // switch to frames inside the webpage
    driver.switchTo().frame("GB_frame"); // 1st frame
    driver.switchTo().frame(0); // 2nd frame
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys("Tester");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys("Automater");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("test11@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Ppassword")).sendKeys("prd1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("confirmPPassword")).sendKeys("pass7ord1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("State")).sendKeys("I");

    driver.findElement(By.id("myInput")).sendKeys("Mike Ward");

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.name("term")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("formAccSubmit")).click();

    assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id("errorContainer")).getText(),
            "The Email field must contain a valid email address.");

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: How do you know its input-ing text? Does it login?

Comment: Are you sure you're retrieving an input field and not some div that's overlayed on it?

Comment: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="24" value="" class="textbox" id="firstName" name="firstName" style="visibility: visible;">

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=307&q=sendkeys&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, your problem will solve, remove OR.getProperty and use your attributes.

```
String txtuserzipID = OR.getProperty("txt_UserZip_ID"); 
WebElement txtuserZipInput = driver.findElement(By.id(txtuserzipID));
txtuserZipInput.clear(); 
txtuserZipInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(79081));
txtuserZipInput = driver.findElement(By.id(txtuserzipID));
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("txt_UserZip_ID"))), 
"").perform();
```

Hope it will work and resolve your problem.
Thanks

Comment: Some times the web application will not save the typed data in the fields. I too have faced the same problem. After that by using the above code, I have resolved my problem..